# How to set the distance between axis label and axis in bokeh?

Tags: plot, bokeh, styling

one can use `p.yaxis[0].axis_label_standoff` for setting the distance between y label and y thick labels.

I would like to set the distance between the y label and y axis (or y thicks). So that all plots have y labels and y axis aligned, regardless of the length of y thick labels.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in functionality to do that. However, you can create a custom Axis class that extends one of the Bokeh's built-in ones and override its `_draw_axis_label` method to do what you need.